# LibGDX - Sprites to texture using FBO

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx, framebuffer, blending, fbo

I am working on a simple painting app using LibGDX, and I am having trouble getting it to "paint" properly with the setup I am using.  The way I am trying to do this is to draw with sprites, and add these individual sprites into a background texture, using LibGDX's FBO commands, when it is appropriate.

The problem I am having is something relating to blending, in that when the sprites are added to this texture that I am building, any transparent pixels of the sprite that are on top of pixels that have been drawn to previous will be brightened up substantially, which obviously doesn't look very good.  The following is what the result looks like, using a circle with a green>red gradient as the "brush".  The top row is part of the background texture now, while the bottom one is still in its purely sprite drawn form.

http://i238.photobucket.com/albums/ff307/Muriako/hmm.png

Basically, the transparent areas of each sprite are brightening anything below them, and I need to make them completely transparent.  I have messed around with many different blending mode combinations and couldn't find one that was any better.  GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA for example did not have this problem, but instead the transparent pixels of each sprite seem to be lowered in alpha and even take on some of the color from the layer below, which seemed even more annoying.

I will be happy to post any code snippets on request, but my code has become a bit of mess since I started trying to fix these problems, so I would rather only put up the necessary bits as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

What order are you drawing the sprites in?  Alpha blending only works with respect to pixels already in the target, so you have to draw all alpha-containing things (and everything "behind" them) in Z order to get the right result.  I'm using `.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Comment: The sprites are being drawn in the same order they are placed down, so they are always on top of any that were added before it.  I made a small mistake in my original post, which I've now fixed, but I was using "GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA" to get the effect shown in the screenshot.  Using the same blend mode you suggested I get the effect I mentioned in the original post, though it was incorrect earlier.  Sorry for any confusion that may have caused!